# заполнение массива с клавиатуры

Tags: java

Написал программу,которая считывает количество чисел n,а потом считывает числа через пробел и записывает в массив,но что-то не работает

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Class {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int k[] = new int[n];
        k = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Заполненый массив");
        System.out.print(k + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: В чем выражается «не работает»?

Comment: Цикла нет, смещения по элементам массива нет и записи в следующий элемент соответственно тоже нет.

Comment: nextInt() читает одно число, а не массив

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас нет цикла, в котором бы числа записывались в массив, также Вы его не выводите на экран.
Если у вас определенное количество элементов, то код правильнее будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Class {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int k[] = new int[10];
    for(int i=0; i<k.length;i++){ //перебор всех элементов
           k[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Заполненный массив");

        for(int i=0; i<k.length;i++){ //перебор всех элементов
           System.out.print(k[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Это если я правильно поняла суть вашего вопроса.

Уточнение согласно условию:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Class {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Кол-во элементов массива:");
    Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = n.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Элементы массива:");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int k[] = new int[num];
    for(int i=0; i<k.length;i++){
        k[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Заполненный массив");
        for(int i=0; i<k.length;i++){
        System.out.print(k[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Судя по всему, в первом вводе задаётся размер массива.

Comment: Да,в первом вводе задаётся размер массива.

Comment: @Человек , добавила код

Comment: Спасибо,заработало.Надо было цикл мне поставить